# I'm a bit confused about how to solve this warning and error

Tags: c, random, numbers, user-input

I have to make a code where a random number is generated between 1 and 100, and a user has to input numbers until they figure it out. At the end, it has to tell them how many guesses it took them to figure it out. I have one error and one warning, neither of which I know how to handle. I tried looking them up but I couldn't really find something to help me:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:18:26: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘time’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         srand((unsigned) time(&t));
                          ^~~~
main.c:43:1: error: expected ‘while’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
main.c:43:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Here's the code I'm working with for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char name[1024];
    int i, n;
    time_t t;
    int randNum;
    int userTries;
    int inpUser;

    printf("Please enter your name: \n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello %s\n, we're going to play a game where you guess a secret number. I will tell you if you're too high or too low, and I will also tell you at the end how many guesses you took.\n", name);

    //initializes the random number generator
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //calculates a random number between 100 and 1*/
    randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

    do {
        printf("Guess a random number, but I bet you'll get it wrong:\n");
        scanf("%d", inpUser);
        if (inpUser == randNum) {
            printf("That's the number! Maybe I underestimated you.\n");
        }
        else if (inpUser > randNum) {
            printf("You're a little high there, bud.\n");
        }
        else if (inpUser < randNum) {
            printf("Maybe go a little higher next time?\n");

            userTries++;
        }

        while (randNum != inpUser);
        printf("Congratulations, you actually did it! That's the number! It took you %d tries, but you did it!", userTries);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the indentation and the problem will become apparent.

Comment: If it is not == and it's not > then it must be <. Only 2 tests, any 2, needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you should enclose the print statement inside curly braces{}. Using a semicolon ends the while statement. Also, you declared time_t, but you are then using simply time. No variable time was declared.

Answer (score 0):

I correct your program :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    char name[1024];
    int i, n;
    time_t t;
    int randNum = 0;
    int userTries = 0;
    int inpUser = 0;

    printf("Please enter your name: \n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello %s\n, we're going to play a game where you guess a secret number. I will tell you if you're too high or too low, and I will also tell you at the end how many guesses you took.\n", name);

    //initializes the random number generator
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //calculates a random number between 100 and 1*/
    randNum = rand() %100 + 1;

    do {
        printf("Guess a random number, but I bet you'll get it wrong:\n");
        scanf("%d", &inpUser);
        if (inpUser == randNum) {
            printf("That's the number! Maybe I underestimated you.\n");
        }
        else if (inpUser > randNum) {
            printf("You're a little high there, bud.\n");
        }
        else if (inpUser < randNum) {
            printf("Maybe go a little higher next time?\n");

            userTries++;

        }
    }
    while (randNum != inpUser);
    printf("Congratulations, you actually did it! That's the number! It took you %d tries, but you did it!", userTries);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for remarque (it time.h instead ctime)

Comment: When I try to run this, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) ...Program finished with exit code 139.

Comment: @Varian it is corrected but at the origin, I corrected that the syntactic and compilation 
 aspects, and not the execution, nor the functional one